# Как accesskey взаимодействует с не ссылочными тегами?

Tags: html, html5

[Здесь](http://programmerbook.ru/html/global-attributes/accesskey/) сказано, что параметр `accesskey` применяется для всех элементов, но во всех примерах он используется для тега `а`.
Это логично, ссылку имеет смысл выделять клавишами, но все же, как он взаимодействует с другими тегами, например `h1`?

Например такой код?

```
<h1 accesskey="x">Lorem ipsum dolor.</h1>
```

Comment: Ну можно tabindex добавить.